# Como retornar a previsão do tempo através da API do previsaodotempo.org?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando retornar uma consulta de previsão de tempo através da API do http://www.previsaodotempo.org mas não estou obtendo sucesso. Onde estou errando?

```js
$.getJSON('http://www.previsaodotempo.org/api.php?city=rio+de+janeiro', function(data){
    $('.temperatura').text( "Temperatura:" );
}).done(function() {
    $('.sucesso').text( "second success" );
})
.fail(function() {
    $('.sucesso').text( "error" );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class='sucesso'></span>
<span class='temperatura'></span>
```

Comment: por favor, complete sua pergunta, esta muito fraca, porte o resto do codigo...

Comment: @Jeiferson qual a dúvida? Estou tentando consultar a URL e está falhando, quero saber porquê está disto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema é que você está tentando fazer uma requisição cross-domain via ajax, o que não é permitido devido a [Política de mesma origem](http://www.wikiwand.com/pt/Pol%C3%ADtica_de_mesma_origem) (a menos que o domínio alvo suporte [CORS](http://www.wikiwand.com/pt/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)).

[JSONP](http://www.wikiwand.com/pt/JSONP) seria uma alternativa, mas a API do previsaodotempo.org não parece suportar isso.

Não sei se é viável para você, mas uma outra alternativa é criar um arquivo no seu servidor local para servir de proxy. Este arquivo faria a requisição à API e retornaria o JSON pra você. Desta forma sua chamada ajax passaria a ser local.

Caso seu servidor suporte PHP, você pode usar o seguinte:

PHP (api.php):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8;'); 
exit(file_get_contents("http://www.previsaodotempo.org/api.php?city=" . $_GET['city']));
```

Javascript:

```
$.getJSON('http://[endereço-do-seu-site]/api.php?city=rio+de+janeiro', function(data){
    $('.temperatura').text( "Temperatura:" );
}).done(function() {
    $('.sucesso').text( "second success" );
})
.fail(function() {
    $('.sucesso').text( "error" );
});
```

Seu Javascript receberá exatamente o que a API retornar.